# Creating multi project application

Tags: multiple-inheritance, aurelia, project-structure

I'm new to Aurelia and I want to create an app that call for other apps.

Example : I want to create 3 projects, project A, project B and common and wish to call common in both projects A and B.

I've tried some examples with npm and others, but this never works.

Is there a simple way for doing that ?

Answer (score 2):

Best way to utilize your common features for your 2 projects is to use an aurelia plugin.
Aurelia plugins are very good at encapsulting reusable components.

JSPM, the default package manager for Aurelia, supports private github repo and even local ones (easier during the early development phase).
So intalling your plugin in your project will be as easy as typing something like that :

`jspm install github:mygithubaccount/myplugin@master`

I would advise you to start reading one of plugin authoring blog post, then check the repo plugin to see how to package yours.
Check the blog post about [AureliaFlux](http://blog.durandal.io/2015/07/23/creating-reactive-loosely-coupled-apps-with-aurelia-and-flux-episode-1/), it is worth reading.

You can also use the [aurelia skeleton-plugin](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-plugin) repository as a starting point.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I've tried to create aurelia plugins and install them with jspm, but I always get errors on keywords inside my code like "import" "export" and others.  The following link is one of many tutos I've tried, but always failed on keywords http://mammal.io/articles/using-es6-today/

Comment: What IDE/Editor are you using ? Does your editor support ES6/JS Harmony ?

Comment: i am using eclipse for code and terminal for compiling.